# Recent modification to image upload feature?

Tags: support, images

Today, I found that clicking on the "image upload" icon now presents one with what *appears* to be a dashed "drag-and-drop" box containing the message "Click Here to upload image".  (Just a day or two ago, I was getting the file selection window I'd been getting for close to two years.)  However, I am unable to get this to accept an image by dragging either a .png or a .jpg into it.

Has there been an alteration to this function recently? Is there something in particular I should know about using this feature now?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, SE rolled out a new image uploader today. It looks fancier, and allows to drag and drop images into it. There were some [issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259186/259867) on sites with old CSS model, but not here as far as I know.

I am able to use it for upload: here is a .png file I dragged and dropped. If you are unable to upload, I suggest restarting the browser; if it persists, post a bug report here, specifying the browser and operating system.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  It must be so new I couldn't even find anything on the boards about it.  My version of Safari, which is what I generally use, is pretty (darn) old, but I did get the upload to work with Firefox 25 (which just updated on my machine).